# Zeus for iOS devices

Tags: ios, botnet

Is there a known variant of Zeus which attacks iOS based mobile devices?
I have read about versions for Android and Symbian , wondering if iOS is vulnerable to it as well.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there has never been a version of ZitMo (Zeus in the Mobile) for iOS.  The variants for Android and Symbian have been fairly rudimentary, the most common Android one was just an unsigned APK that users were tricked into installing.  This is not possible in iOS without jailbreaking or compromising the device due to the requirement that iPhone apps be signed and delivered via the app store.